# Possible to get Lat/Lon coordinates of triangle vertex point?

Tags: point, coordinates, latitude-longitude, vertices

I have two known points (A and B) on latitude / longitude coordinates.
Certainly I know the distance between A and B in meters.

I have third point C with unknown coordinates, but I know the distance between AC and BC in meters.

Is it possible to get the lat/lon coordinates of point C with math formula?

---

Here is an example:

The all known distances between coordinate points are:

AB = 120.9234 meters
AC = 226.7206 meters
BC = 213.1376 meters

The known coordinates of A and B point:

A lat = 47.49784;
A lon = 19.08939;

B lat = 47.49893;
B lon = 19.08941;

and I calculated all angles of triangle in deg:
B: 80.341932306607 
A: 31.722055823679
C: 67.936011869714

and I measured the result what I looking for in map:
Lat: 47.498575374822
Lon: 19.09129858017

but I like to use a math formula to get these two coordinates of point C using the upper input values.

Comment: On a plane or on a sphere or on an ellipsoid?

Comment: The formula can be work on a plane because the distances are very low, 10-100 meters only. I just don't want to change the coordinate system for the math formula if it is possible, and I want to get the result in lat/lon.

Comment: Sorry, I modified vanishing point to vertex on the title.

Comment: So you know all the distances?  (AB, AC, BC)

Comment: Yes. I know all distances between all 3 points in meters. And not just distances, I know all angles in degree or radian if required. I just want to know the coordinates of third point.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know AB, AC, and BC, then the answer is yes.  It requires trigonometry.  The following assumes a flat plane and that points A anb B are not on the same line of latitude or longitude.  To get the lat/long of C you need to figure out the ΔX and ΔY from a known point (let's use A).

You're going to need the value of the angle θ, which is 90-a-λ

Let ΔXB and ΔYB be the lat/long difference from A to B (both of which have known coordinates). From basic trigonometry we know that sin(λ) = ΔYB/AB.  Therefore **λ = arcsin(ΔYB/AB)**.

By the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) cos(a) = (AB²+AC²-BC²)/(2*AB*AC), which means **a = arccos((AB²+AC²-BC²)/(2×AB×AC))**

Therefore **θ = 90 - arccos((AB²+AC²-BC²)/(2×AB×AC)) - arcsin(ΔYB/AB)**

With θ calculated, we're back to basic trigonometry again: sin(θ)= ΔX/AC and cos(θ) = ΔY/AC.  Therefore **ΔX = sin(θ)×AC** and **ΔY = cos(θ)×AC**.  Just add those values to the coordinates of A, and you have your answer.

[image]

**TLDR version:**

- C(x) = A(x) + AC × sin(90 - arccos((AB²+AC²-BC²)/(2×AB×AC)) -
  arcsin((A(y)-B(y))/AB))
- C(y) = A(y) + AC × cos(90 - arccos((AB²+AC²-BC²)/(2×AB×AC)) - arcsin((A(y)-B(y))/AB))

Comment: I implemented this formula, and the result is close to the measured values but not exactly same.

Answer (score 0):

I trying the formula, and the result is close to the answer, but something wrong.

I have coordinates of A and B points:

```
        $Ax = 47.497846896196;
        $Ay = 19.089394211769;

        $Bx = 47.498934174013;
        $By = 19.089415669441;
```

x is latitude, y is longitude.

The distance between A and B is

```
        120.9047 meters
```

This is counted by simple formula. If I use MySQL GLength(), I got another values, but I think the trigonometry formula is good too.

Counting:

```
        $DxAB = ($Ax - $Bx); = -0.0010872778169997
        $DyAB = ($Ay - $By); = -2.1457671998348E-5

        $Lambda = asin($DyAB / $AB); = -1.774759128334E-7

        $aAngle = acos((pow($AB, 2) + pow($AC, 2) - pow($BC, 2)) / (2 * ($AC * $AB))); = 1.0422581825838

        $Theta = deg2rad(90 - rad2deg($aAngle) - rad2deg($Lambda)); = 0.52853832168699

        $DX = asin($Theta); = 0.55687780990758
        $DY = acos($Theta); = 1.0139185168873

        $Cx = $DX + $Ax; = 48.054724706104
        $Cy = $DY + $Ay; = 20.103312728656
```

but the result we measured is:

```
        47.498575374822 and 19.09129858017
```

While I have 2 different list of distances between points (counted by trigonometry and by database GLength()) the output of formulas are not exactly same as we measured:

Distances between input coords by trigonometry:

```
        $AB = 120.9047;
        $AC = 164.3976;
        $BC = 146.9635;
```

distances between (same) coords by database handler:

```
        $AB = 120.9234;
        $AC = 226.7206;
        $BC = 213.1376;
```

I understand why we can got different distances.

The result of this formula if using database handler's distances as input:

```
        $Cx = $DX + $Ax; = 47.893151605351
        $Cy = $DY + $Ay; = 20.264885829409
```

This result is closer than the previous one, but not valid. Maybe something wrong in my side?

Comment: I think I screwed up.  sin(θ)=ΔX/AC , _therefore_ **ΔX = AC×sin(θ)**  I'll go fix that now.

Comment: One more thing maybe help to found the problem. The "real" difference between the lat/lon coordinates of point A and point C is 0.00072847862600156 and 0.0019043684010001. But the difference using the formula is 0.3953047091551 and 1.1754916176398

Comment: The answer is always 2 points

Comment: Maybe the error is getting introduced with the conversions back and forth to and from radians?  Try running the whole thing using only degrees or using only radians.

Comment: I removed the conversion from the formula $Theta = ((M_PI / 2) - ($aAngle) - ($Lambda)); but the result is exactly same than before.

Comment: Finnaly I converted lat/lon to X/Y. With this conversion the known points changed to: Ax = 5262259, Ay = 356102, Bx = 5262380, By = 356106. The coordinates of C what I looking for is Cx = 5262337, Cy = 356247. The difference between the coordinates of point A and C is Dx = 78, Dy = 145. But the differences with the formula is Dx = 0.4314342600821 and Dy = 1.1393620667128

Answer (score 0):

I cancelled latitude and longitude coordinates as inputs, and I would like to solve a simple example with any unit.

[image: Image with result what I want to get]

I have all inputs on the image, but no Cx and Cy. What is the best method to get these data as accurate result? I tried to implement formulas to programming language, but not always returned acceptable result. I have non 90 degree, non equilateral triangles only.

thanks!

Comment: You need the acute angle between either AC or BC and the x-axis.  Then you can use basic trigonometry to figure out the ΔX and ΔY with regards to either B or A.  I'm not sure where the error is in the formulas I wrote out above, but it _should_ work once the errors are removed.  Another option is to use the intersection of 2 circles method described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect